TinyMCE Toolbar ScrollBar not working properly with Quasar Framework
We have a Vue2, Nuxt2 project based on Quasar Framework. We've added a TinyMCE doc editor to it with a toolbar.
The toolbar is supposed to have a horizontal scroll in case all of the buttons don't fit into the screen. The scrollbar appears automatically but clicking on the scrollbar hides the toolbar so it's basically not usable...
Here's our doc editor config:
const defaultConfig: RawEditorSettings = {
  inline: true,
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: true,
  browser_spellcheck: true,
  schema: 'html5-strict',
  fixed_toolbar_container: '#doceditor-toolbar',
  style_formats_merge: false,
  toolbar_mode: 'scrolling',
  toolbar_sticky: true,
  language: 'ru',

  style_formats: [
    {
      title: 'Размер шрифта',
      items: [
        { title: '10', format: 'style-fs-10' },
        { title: '12', format: 'style-fs-12' },
        { title: '13', format: 'style-fs-13' },
        { title: '13.5', format: 'style-fs-13_5' },
        { title: '14', format: 'style-fs-14' },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Межбуквенный интервал',
      items: [
        { title: '+10%', format: 'style-ls-1' },
        { title: '+20%', format: 'style-ls-2' },
        { title: '+30%', format: 'style-ls-3' },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Межсловный интервал',
      items: [
        { title: 'x2', format: 'style-ws-2' },
        { title: 'x4', format: 'style-ws-4' },
        { title: 'x6', format: 'style-ws-6' },
        { title: 'x8', format: 'style-ws-8' },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Межстрочный интервал',

      items: [
        { title: '1,0', format: 'style-lh-1' },
        { title: '1,15', format: 'style-lh-2' },
        { title: '1,2', format: 'style-lh-1-2' },
        { title: '1,5', format: 'style-lh-3' },
        { title: '2,0', format: 'style-lh-4' },
        { title: '2,5', format: 'style-lh-5' },
        { title: '3,0', format: 'style-lh-6' },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Стиль абзаца',
      items: [
        { title: 'С красной строкой', format: 'p' },
        {
          title: 'Без красной строки',
          format: 'div',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  formats: {
    ...STYLE_FS.reduce((acc, v) => {
      acc['style-' + v] = { inline: 'span', classes: v }
      return acc
    }, {}),
    ...STYLE_LS.reduce((acc, v) => {
      acc['style-' + v] = { inline: 'span', classes: v }
      return acc
    }, {}),
    ...STYLE_WS.reduce((acc, v) => {
      acc['style-' + v] = { inline: 'span', classes: v }
      return acc
    }, {}),
    ...STYLE_LH.reduce((acc, v) => {
      acc['style-' + v] = {
        selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table',
        classes: v,
      }
      return acc
    }, {}),
    alignleft: {
      selector: DEFAULT_BLOCK_SELECTOR,
      classes: 'ta-tl',
    },
    aligncenter: {
      selector: DEFAULT_BLOCK_SELECTOR,
      classes: 'ta-tc',
    },
    alignright: {
      selector: DEFAULT_BLOCK_SELECTOR,
      classes: 'ta-tr',
    },
    alignjustify: {
      selector: DEFAULT_BLOCK_SELECTOR,
      classes: 'ta-tj',
    },
    alignfull: {
      selector: DEFAULT_BLOCK_SELECTOR,
      classes: 'ta-tf',
    },
    bordersolid: [
      { inline: 'th', classes: 'td-st' },
      { inline: 'td', classes: 'td-st' },
    ],
    bordercollaps: [
      { inline: 'tbody', classes: 'tb-st' },
      { inline: 'table', classes: 'tb-st' },
    ],
    bold: [
      { inline: 'strong', remove: 'all' },
      { inline: 'span', styles: { fontWeight: 'bold' } },
      { inline: 'b', remove: 'all' },
    ],
    italic: [
      { inline: 'i', remove: 'all' },
      { inline: 'em', remove: 'all' },
      { inline: 'span', styles: { fontStyle: 'italic' } },
    ],
    underline: { inline: 'u' },
    strikethrough: { inline: 'del' },
    div: [
      { block: 'div' },
      { block: 'p', classes: 'no-indent', remove: 'all' },
    ],
  },
  setup: (editor) => {
    'JustifyLeft,JustifyCenter,JustifyRight,JustifyFull,JustifyFull2,JustifyNone'
      .split(',')
      .forEach((command) => {
        editor.addCommand(command, (ui, v) => {
          let align = command.substring(7).toLocaleLowerCase()
          if (align == 'full') align = 'justify'
          if (align == 'full2') align = 'full'
          // Remove all other alignments first
          'left,center,right,justify,full'.split(',').forEach(function (name) {
            if (align !== name) {
              editor.formatter.remove('align' + name)
            }
          })
          if (align !== 'none') {
            editor.formatter.toggle('align' + align)
          }
        })
      })
    editor.on('SwitchMode', function () {
      if (editor.readonly) {
        editor.readonly = true
      }
    })

    editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
      if (e.command === 'mceToggleFormat') {
        // console.log('mceToggleFormat', e)
        if (STYLE_FS.indexOf(e.value.split('style-').pop()) > -1) {
          STYLE_FS.forEach(function (name) {
            if (e.value !== 'style-' + name) {
              editor.formatter.remove('style-' + name)
            }
          })
        } else if (STYLE_LS.indexOf(e.value.split('style-').pop()) > -1) {
          STYLE_LS.forEach(function (name) {
            if (e.value !== 'style-' + name) {
              editor.formatter.remove('style-' + name)
            }
          })
        } else if (STYLE_WS.indexOf(e.value.split('style-').pop()) > -1) {
          STYLE_WS.forEach(function (name) {
            if (e.value !== 'style-' + name) {
              editor.formatter.remove('style-' + name)
            }
          })
        } else if (STYLE_LH.indexOf(e.value.split('style-').pop()) > -1) {
          STYLE_LH.forEach(function (name) {
            if (e.value !== 'style-' + name) {
              editor.formatter.remove('style-' + name)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
    editor.on('keypress', function (evt) {
      if ((evt.ctrlKey || evt.shiftKey) && evt.code == 'Space') {
        evt.cancelBubble = true
        evt.preventDefault()
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation()
        editor.execCommand('mceNonBreaking')
      }
    })

    editor.addCommand('mceCorrectSpaces', function (ui, v) {
      const el = editor.getElement()
      const sel = editor && editor.selection && editor.selection.getRng()
      const selr = sel && [
        sel.startContainer.nodeName === '#text'
          ? sel.startContainer.parentElement
          : sel.startContainer,
        sel.startOffset,
        sel.endContainer.nodeName === '#text'
          ? sel.endContainer.parentElement
          : sel.endContainer,
        sel.endOffset,
      ]
      let n, walk, prevnode, str, lstr
      const correct = (node) => {
        TEXT_2_REPLACE.forEach(
          (patern) =>
            (node.data = node.data?.toString().replace(patern[0], patern[1]))
        )
        lstr = prevnode?.data?.toString() || ''
        if (lstr?.[lstr.length - 1] == ' ') {
          str = node?.data?.toString() || ''
          if (str[0] == ' ' || str[0] == ' ' || !str) {
            if (str.length < 2) {
              node.remove()
              return
            } else node.data = str.slice(1)
          }
        }

        TEXT_2_REPLACE.forEach(
          (patern) =>
            (node.data = node.data?.toString().replace(patern[0], patern[1]))
        )
        if (node.data.toString()) prevnode = node
      }
      if (!selr || (selr && selr[0] == selr[2] && selr[1] == selr[3])) {
        walk = document.createNodeIterator(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null)
        while ((n = walk.nextNode())) {
          correct(n)
        }
      } else {
        for (
          let node = selr[0];
          node !== null && typeof node !== 'number';
          node = node.nextSibling
        ) {
          if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
            correct(node)
          } else {
            walk = document.createNodeIterator(
              node,
              NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
              null /* ,
              true */
            )
            prevnode = null
            while ((n = walk.nextNode())) correct(n)
            if (node == sel.endContainer) break
          }
        }
      }
    })
    editor.addCommand('mceNonBreakingHyphen', function (ui, v) {
      const nbsp = (
        editor.plugins.visualchars
          ? editor.plugins.visualchars.isEnabled()
          : false
      )
        ? '<span class="mce-nbhyphen">&#8209;</span>'
        : '&#8209;'
      editor.insertContent(nbsp)
      editor.dom.setAttrib(
        editor.dom.select('mce-nbhyphen'),
        'data-mce-bogus',
        '1'
      )
    })
    editor.addCommand('mceNDash', function (ui, v) {
      const nbsp = (
        editor.plugins.visualchars
          ? editor.plugins.visualchars.isEnabled()
          : false
      )
        ? '<span class="mce-ndash"> &ndash; </span>'
        : ' &ndash; '
      editor.insertContent(nbsp)
      editor.dom.setAttrib(
        editor.dom.select('mce-ndash'),
        'data-mce-bogus',
        '1'
      )
    })
    editor.addCommand('toggleCase', (command, ui) => {
      const val = editor.selection.getContent({ format: 'text' })
      const _val = val.split(/\s+/gm).join('')
      const editor_range = editor.selection.getRng()
      // console.log(editor.selection)
      editor.selection.setContent(
        _val[0].toLowerCase() == _val[0]
          ? val
              .split(' ')
              .map((el) => el && el[0].toUpperCase() + el.slice(1))
              .join(' ')
          : _val[1].toLowerCase() == _val[1]
          ? val.toUpperCase()
          : val.toLowerCase()
      )

      editor.selection.setRng(editor_range)
    })
    editor.addCommand('pagebreak', (e) => {
      editor.insertContent('<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>')
      editor.insertContent(
        '<div class="pagebreakcustom" style="color: grey;page-break-after: always; border: 1px dotted; height: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 90px;display: flex;margin: 30px 0 30px 0;"><p style="text-align: center;width: 100%;margin: -4px;font-size: 10pt;">Разрыв страницы<p></div>'
      )
    })

    editor.ui.registry.addButton('alignfull', {
      tooltip: 'Full justify',
      icon: 'align-justify',
      // active: false,
      onAction: function (api) {
        editor.execCommand('JustifyFull2', false)
      },
      onSetup: (e) => {
        const handler = (state: boolean) => {
          e.setDisabled(!state)
        }

        return function (buttonApi) {
          if (editor.formatter) {
            editor.formatter.formatChanged('alignfull', handler)
          } else {
            editor.on('init', () => {
              editor.formatter.formatChanged('alignfull', handler)
            })
          }
        }
      },
    })
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('nonbreakinghyphen', {
      tooltip: 'Nonbreaking hyphen',
      text: '–',
      onAction: function (api) {
        editor.execCommand('mceNonBreakingHyphen', false)
      },
    })
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('ndash', {
      tooltip: 'Ndash',
      text: '—',
      onAction: function (api) {
        editor.execCommand('mceNDash', false)
      },
    })
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('togglecase', {
      tooltip: 'Toggle case',
      text: 'Аб',
      onAction: function (api) {
        editor.execCommand('toggleCase', false)
      },
    })
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('correctors', {
      tooltip: 'Коррекция предлогов, дефисов и дат',
      text: 'Коррекция',
      onAction: function (api) {
        editor.execCommand('mceCorrectSpaces', false)
      },
    })
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('pagebreakcustom', {
      tooltip: 'Разрыв страницы',
      icon: 'page-break',
      onAction: function (api) {
        editor.execCommand('pagebreak', false)
      },
    })
  },
}


So basically: I click on the document - it comes into focus, the toolbar appears. If the screen is too small - the toolbar appears with a horizontal scrollbar. I can scroll through the toolbar with my mouse wheel when the shift key is pressed. But once i try using the scrollbar by clicking on it with my mouse - the editor goes out of focus, the toolbar disappears.
At first we thought maybe there was a problem with the z-index of the elements, but changing that doesn't change anything. We created a new Vue2, Quasar App and managed to recreate this problem: wrapping the page into a q-layout broke the scrollbar logic (Like the q-layout is somehow taking the focus from the scrollbar onto itself or whatever??). But we cannot get rid of the q-layout in our actual site as basically everything is wrapped into said q-layout, and has been wrapped for ages.
Does anybody know what might be the problem and if there's a solution?
I have tried disabling the clicking on the scrollbar in the config of the editor (using stopPropagation() on the entire container of the toolbar - doesn't change anything. I feel like there's something crucial that I'm missing...
We still want to be able to scroll it by dragging the scrollbar across the screen...
